# decrypting encrypted POST parameters

Tags: authentication, cryptography, http-post, hmac, cryptoapi

In an encrypted POST request to a web service, I see two important parameters: `hmac` and `ciphertext`. Using these, I want to decrypt the ciphertext. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot decrypt the ciphertext without the encryption key (unless the crypto is broken, but the fact that there is also a HMAC leads me to believe it probably isn't).